# Embed command discord.js character limit

Tags: node.js, command, character, discord.js, limit

I'm making a command to identify the people who have a role, and he will list all the people with the role, but he ends up exceeding the character limit, because there are many people with that role, what could I do?

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

exports.run = (bot, message, args) => {
    let staff = bot.emojis.get("718580359704477766")

    const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#91e0ff")
    .setTitle(`${staff} **| Lista de Staffers do Server**`)
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
    .addField(`Equipes Staffers:`, `<a:red2:721546087701282898>・<@&718861978864582707> - (${message.guild.roles.get('718861978864582707').members.size} staffs)`)
    .setFooter(`Atenciosamente - ${bot.user.username}`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setTimestamp()

    message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
        await msg.react('721546087701282898')

        const collector = msg.createReactionCollector((r, u) => (r.emoji.id ===  '721244453997641758', '721546087701282898', '721546088279965829', '721546088657584150', '721546089190260766', '721546089622405121', '721546089693446145' && u.id === message.author.id))

        collector.on("collect", async r => {
            r.remove(message.author)
            switch (r.emoji.id) {
            case '721546087701282898':
            msg.reactions.forEach(r=>{ r.users.filter(u =>u === message.author).forEach(bot=>{ r.remove(bot) }) })
                msg.edit(new RichEmbed()
                .setColor("#91e0ff")
                .setTitle(`**Lista de Registro:**`)
                .addField(`Registros:`, msg.guild.roles.get('718861978864582707').members.map(m => `<@${m.id}>`).join(`\n`))
                .setFooter(`Atenciosamente - ${bot.user.username}`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
            )}
        })
    })
}

exports.help = {
    name: "lista"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple `trimString` function to ensure that the string is less than 1024 characters:

```js
trimString = (str, max) => ((str.length > max) ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str);

trimString("hi, how are you today?", 10);//"hi, how..."
```

Comment: sorry to ask but how would the command look? i'm new to javascript.